# Нужно достать слово из кортежа, а кортеж находится в списке кортежей. Django

Tags: html, django, django-model

Есть модель с выбором:

```
INTEREST_CHOICES = [
        ('Low High', 'Не важно'),
        ('High', 'Важно'),
        ('Very High', 'Очень важно'),
    ]
class Todo(models.Model):
    interest = models.CharField(default = 'Low High', choices=INTEREST_CHOICES, max_length = 15)
```

и надо достать слова Не важно, Важно и т.д. в html. **{{todo.interest}}** не работает.
выглядеть должно примерно так:

```
<h1>{{todo.name}}</h1>
<h2>{{todo.interest}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примеры с кусками кода.

models.py

```
INTEREST_CHOICES = [
    ("Low High", "Не важно"),
    ("High", "Важно"),
    ("Very High", "Очень важно"),
]


class Todo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    interest = models.CharField(
        default="Low High", choices=INTEREST_CHOICES, max_length=15
    )
```

views.py:

```
def test(request):
    result = Todo.objects.all()
    return render(request, "todo/index.html", context={"todos": result})
```

template index.html

```
{% for todo in todos %}
    <h1>{{ todo.name }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ todo.get_interest_display }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую